# Code only works if I initialize object inside the implementation { }

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

The next code only works if `LBYouTubePlayerController* controller;` is inside  `@implementation ViewController`. Can someone explain to me why I get this behavior and what's the difference ?

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LBYouTube.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<LBYouTubePlayerControllerDelegate> 

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    LBYouTubePlayerController* controller;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
      controller  = [[LBYouTubePlayerController alloc] initWithYouTubeURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UlbCgB9vms"] quality:LBYouTubeVideoQualityLarge];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);
    controller.view.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
```

If i'll move `LBYouTubePlayerController* controller;` and put it inside `viewDidLoad` the video won't load:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
LBYouTubePlayerController* controller  = [[LBYouTubePlayerController alloc] initWithYouTubeURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UlbCgB9vms"] quality:LBYouTubeVideoQualityLarge];
    controller.delegate = self; ....}
```

Comment: Do you use ARC? Either way, you want to have reference to LBYouTubePlayerController. If you don't use ARC, you have memory leak without reference, and if using ARC, instance is deallocated and only view is alive which means LBYouTubePlayerController can't load viewo, call delgate methods etc.

Comment: This is actually a strange way to it. Usually you would have ONE view controller, but is looks like you are using two. If you don't keep a property reference the LBYouTubePlayerController would be deallocated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your working example, you're using an [instance variable](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable&ei=XfR_UdzxDuqs4ATNxIDwDw&usg=AFQjCNE8r7PNtagS_iV5oX5-nz9X65mUKw&sig2=DUGivBg6jLsElyHK5aMEPg&bvm=bv.45645796,d.bGE) (ivar). In the non-working example you're using a [local variable](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable&ei=avR_Ud7RBfTV4QSt0ICIBg&usg=AFQjCNH8ZH7cSm5woZAvlx3IroiOZ3gqAQ&sig2=NgYzdxvGr-M4me4WXgUEng&bvm=bv.45645796,d.bGE). Memory is handled differently for these variables.
With [Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), any object declared and initialized in a block will be automatically released (and in this case deallocated) after the last use of that object in that block. By declaring an instance variable instead, as you do in your working example, you prevent that. An ivar is only released once the owning object (ViewController) is itself deallocated.

Answer (score 1):

This is the difference between an instance variable and a local variable. Google is your friend for researching this.

An instance variable exists for the lifetime of the object (depending on how you create it). A local variable lasts as long as its scope (in this case, your method).

You need to use an instance variable here so that the controller actually exists long enough for you to use it. Though you can define your instance variable better like this:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) LBYouTubePlayerController *controller;

@end
```

Comment: Note that in this case, you have to access the automatically generated instance variable by prefixing it with an underscore: `_controller`. Or by using the accessor method `[self controller]`. Or using the dot syntax `self.controller`.